# Filter a child picklist in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to convert javascript code from CRM 4.0 to CRM 2011.
I'm having problems with a picklist filter.

My function is on the onchange of the parent picklist. It works the first time but the second it erase everything from my child picklist.

This is the part where I suppose to reset the picklist

```
    if(!oSubPicklist.originalPicklistValues)
{
oSubPicklist.originalPicklistValues = oSubPicklist.getOptions();
}
else
{
oSubPicklist.getOptions = oSubPicklist.originalPicklistValues;
oSubPicklist.setOptions = oSubPicklist.originalPicklistValues;
}
```

And this is the part where i remove all the option not related:
oTempArray is an array with the options that i want to keep. If a check the "oSubPicklist.getOptions.length" the value is the same that my original picklist.

```
    for (var i=oSubPicklist.getOptions.length; i >= 0;i--)
    {
        if(oTempArray[i] != true)
        {
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_product").removeOption(i);
        }
    }
```

Ideas?

Edit: I solved declaring a global var with the originalPickList in the onLoad event and:

```
oSubPicklist.clearOptions();
for (var i=0; i< oSubPicklist.originalPicklistValues.length; i++) 
    {
    for (var j=0; j< oDesiredOptions.length; j++)
        {
        if (i == oDesiredOptions[j])
        {oSubPicklist.addOption(oSubPicklist.originalPicklistValues[i]);}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not very clear to me: May be you could paste all your function code for better understanding but:

1. This is how you get the options from PickList in CRM 2011

   ```
   var myOptionSet = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_product")   //get Control
   var optionsSet = myOptionSet .getAttribute().getOptions();  //get Options
   preferredTimeOptionSet.clearOptions();                    //Clear all options

   //Create a new Option
   var opt1 = new Option();
   opt1.text = "one";
   opt1.value = 1;

   //Add Option
   myOptionSet.addOption(opt1);

   //Remove Option
   myOptionSet.removeOption(1);
   ```

[Good Example here](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2011/12/addremove-optionset-value-at-run-time.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to just "translate" from CRM 4.0 to 2011 cause I have instructions to do that but I took your idea and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do Parent/Child picklists:

```js
function dynamicDropdown(parent, child) {
  filterPicklist(parent, child);
}

function parentListFilter(parent, id) {
  var filter = "";
  if (getParentCode(parent) != "") {
    filter = getParentCode(parent);
  } else {
    // No [ ] match
  }

  return filter;
}

function filterPicklist(parent, child) {
  var parentList = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(parent).getValue();
  var childListControlAttrib = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(child);
  var childListOptions = childListControlAttrib.getOptions();
  var childListControl = Xrm.Page.getControl(child);
  var codeToFilterListOn = parentListFilter(parent, parentList);


  if (codeToFilterListOn != "") {
    childListControl.clearOptions();
    for (var optionIndex in childListOptions) {
      var option = childListOptions[optionIndex];
      // Ignore xx and check for Match
      if (option.text.substring(0, 2) != "xx" && option.text.indexOf(codeToFilterListOn) > -1) {
        childListControl.addOption(option);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Didn't match, show all?
  }
}

function getParentCode(parent) {
  //Get Parent Code Dynamically from inside [ ]
  var filter = "";
  var parentValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(parent).getText();
  if (parentValue && parentValue.indexOf("]") > -1) {
    var parentCode = parentValue.substring(parentValue.indexOf("[") + 1, parentValue.indexOf("]"));
    if (parentCode) {
      filter = parentCode + " | ";
    } else {}
  }
  return filter;
}
```

See more here: [Parent/Child](http://www.lacabeza.com/dependent-dynamic-picklist-option-sets-crm/)